# Preventing navigation via clicking anchor link in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am creating a textbutton using actionscript.
the code is given below.

```
public function createTextButton(parentId){
            var mytext:TextField = new TextField();
            mytext.x = 478;
            mytext.y = 225;
            mytext.height = 20;
            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Hitchcock";
            format.size = 20;
            mytext.defaultTextFormat = format; 
            mytext.textColor =  0xffffff;
            mytext.htmlText = '<a href="j#" >Click Here</a>';

            mytext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,paginationLinkClicked);
            mytext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverButton);
            mytext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOutButton);
            parentId.addChild(mytext);  
        }
```

Now i want the click event of this button to be handled in my event handler function only. It should not navigate away to the 'href' source given upon clicking. 
How can i achieve that.

Comment: If you read my answer to the other question, you can see that I used `<a href="event:something">label</a>` and explained about the `event:` syntax in the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault();` in your event handler once you've finished your custom handling.

From the adobe docs: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/Event.html

> flash.events.Event.preventDefault(): Cancels an event's default behavior if that behavior can be canceled.

---

***Update:***

preventDefault **won't** work in this case.

You'll need to add a `link` event handler and prefix the url with `event:`.  Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
public function createTextButton(event:Event):void
{
    myText.htmlText = '<a href="event:j#">Click Here</a>';
    myText.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, handle_linkClick);
}

protected function handle_linkClick(event:TextEvent):void
{
    var linkText:String = event.text; // Will give you everything after `event:`. In your case: "j#"
    // Custom code goes here....
}
```

TextArea [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextArea.html#event:link) on the link event handler:

> Dispatched when a user clicks a
>   hyperlink in text defined by the
>   htmlText property, where the URL
>   begins with "event:". The remainder of
>   the URL after "event:" is placed in
>   the text property of the link event
>   object.
>
> When you handle the link event, the
>   hyperlink is not automatically
>   executed; you need to execute the
>   hyperlink from within your event
>   handler. You typically use the
>   navigateToURL() method to execute the
>   hyperlink. This allows you to modify
>   the hyperlink, or even prohibit it
>   from occurring, in your application.